# How do I create a jsoncons::json object that will throw an exception when I call the has_key() function?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncons

I'm trying to test the exception handler in a function that I can't modify. I can only pass a `jsoncon::json` object as an argument. Here's the function definition:

```
bool evaluate(jsoncons::json json)
{
    bool ret = false;
    try
    {
        if (json.has_key("key"))
        {
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid JSON\n" << std::endl;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I tried to set up an invalid json object by using a boolean value as the key with

```
std::string data = R"(
{
    true:"value"
})";
```

and then create a json object and call the function with

```
jsoncons::json json = jsoncons::json::parse(data);
evaluate(json);
```

but the parser catches the error and throws an exception. Q: how do I create a `jsoncons::json` object that will throw an exception in the above function?

Comment: Taking a look at the source code, `basic_json::has_key` is `noexcept`, which makes sense since it would be strange to throw an exception for checking whether or not a key is present. I don't think your `catch` is reachable.

Comment: "_but the parser catches the error and throws an exception_" - yes, it refuses to create a `json` object from something it can't parse. Your function doesn't check if the JSON is valid or not. It only checks if a certain _key_ exists in a **valid** `json` object. `bool evaluate(const jsoncons::json& json) { bool ret = json.has_key("key"); if(!ret) std::cerr << "Missing key\n"; return ret; }`

Comment: @NathanPierson Hasn't always been: https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons/commit/ac0054c15200601f051629ee8526c16d1f22c414. I don't know how the function behaved before that change though and it isn't immediately obvious to me.